# SwiftUI 4: NavigationSplitView behaves strangely?

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI 4, there is now a `NavigationSplitView`. I played around with it and detected some strange behaviour.

Consider the following code: When the `content` function returns the plain `Text`, then there is the expected behaviour - tapping a menu item changes the detail view to the related text.

However, when commenting out the first four `case`s, and commenting in the next four, then a tap on "Edit Profile" does not change the detail view display. (Using `@ViewBuilder` does not change this behaviour.)

Any ideas out there about the reasons for that? From my point of view, this may just be a simple bug, but perhaps there are things to be considered that are not documented yet?!

```
struct MainScreen: View {
    
    @State private var menuItems = MenuItem.menuItems
    @State private var menuItemSelection: MenuItem?
    
    var body: some View {

                NavigationSplitView {

                    List(menuItems, selection: $menuItemSelection) { course in

                        Text(course.name).tag(course)
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("HappyFreelancer")
                } detail: {

                    content(menuItemSelection)
                }
                .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
    
    func content(_ selection: MenuItem?) -> some View {

        switch selection {

            case .editProfile:
                return Text("Edit Profile")

            case .evaluateProfile:
                return Text("Evaluate Profile")

            case .setupApplication:
                return Text("Setup Application")

            case .none:
                return Text("none")

//          case .editProfile:
//              return AnyView(EditProfileScreen())
//
//          case .evaluateProfile:
//              return AnyView(Text("Evaluate Profile"))
//
//          case .setupApplication:
//              return AnyView(Text("Setup Application"))
//
//          case .none:
//              return AnyView(Text("none"))
        }
    }
}

struct MainScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {

        MainScreen()
    }
}

enum MenuItem: Int, Identifiable, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    var id: Int { rawValue }

    case editProfile
    case evaluateProfile
    case setupApplication

    var name: String {
        switch self {
            case .editProfile: return "Edit Profile"
            case .evaluateProfile: return "Evaluate Profile"
            case .setupApplication: return "Setup Application"
        }
    }
}

extension MenuItem {

    static var menuItems: [MenuItem] {
        MenuItem.allCases
    }
}

struct EditProfileScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Edit Profile")
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a bug - view builder does not update details (even if content updated).

Comment: There is a bug in the `detail:` portion.

Comment: Also, don't use `AnyView` there is a long explanation why in the Demystifying SwiftUI video

Comment: @loremipsum: thanks for the hint; I know that, this is just a relict from several experiments before. Also with ViewBuilder func the behaviour is obscure.

Comment: @Yrb: thanks for the information, so I just have to wait for the next Xcode beta...

Comment: I even tried to enforce a change by using `.id`:
```NavigationSplitView {

     List(menuItems, selection: $menuItemSelection) { course in

      Text(course.name)
       .tag(course)
     }
     .navigationTitle("Title")
    } detail: {

     content(menuItemSelection)
      .id(id)
    }
    .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    .onChange(of: menuItemSelection, perform: { newValue in id += 1 })
``` 
- but even this does not help...

Comment: Interesting: when applying the `.id(id)` modifier to the `NavigationSplitView` (instead of applying it to the detail view), then the first two (!) menu selections change the detail view. Any change after that are ignored again. Very strange!

Comment: I HOPE it is fixed in the next Beta...

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit in order to force SwiftUI to redraw the details view, I succeeded in this workaround:

- Wrap the `NavigationSplitView` into a `GeometryReader`.
- Apply an `.id(id)` modifier to the `GeometryReader` (e.g., as `@State private var id: Int = 0`)

In this case, any menu item selection leads to a redraw as expected.

However, Apple should fix the bug, which it is obviously.

Comment: That is an absolutely painful hack...

Comment: Definitely - this should be fixed asap by Apple...

Comment: you can also move the sidebar list to its own view with a binding for selection (at least in beta 2)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that wrapping the Sidebar list within its own view will fix this issue:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @State var selection: SidebarItem? = .none
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Sidebar(selection: $selection)
        } content: {
            content(for: selection)
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func content(for item: SidebarItem?) -> some View {
        switch item {
            case .none:
                Text("Select an Item in the Sidebar")
            case .a:
                Text("A")
            case .b:
                Text("B")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind. It just stopped working for enums with associated types

Comment: None of these solutions are working for me.  I am using enums with associated types - is this a bug?   I am on Xcode 14.0.1